# Discrete wavelet transform explaination

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

I don't know if this is the right place to ask questions besides programming, so my apologies if I am wrong in asking this question here.

I am unable to understand the **discrete wavelet transform** on images. I followed [this](http://users.rowan.edu/~polikar/WAVELETS/WTtutorial.html) tutorial and got a brief idea about the theory. But I'm unable to understand w.r.t images.

For example:

[image: chessboard]

Using Matlab's `ndwt2('chess.jpg', 2, 'haar')` function on above chess board , I obtained the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP2ei.jpg) 7 images.

`ndwt2()` returns a structure, whose member `dec` contains the **approximation (A), horizontal (H) , vertical (V) and diagonal (D)** details.

This is where I have problem. What does **A, H, V and D details** of the image mean?

Also, how come is 1st image in the album approximation of the chessboard (assuming approximation means a rough estimate of the image) ? It just has lines where the borders of chess boxes are there. How is that an approximation, or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: It's a bit like Fourier decomposition, the first one have most of the information, then the other wavelet have the details in different directions of your image. You are not at the right place to ask this question, but I wouldn't be able to redirect you in a proper place.

Comment: Ps, a chessboard is not the best picture to see the concept I would say (you don't have details that are carry on the diagonals)